# Reflexivity characterised by reflexive separable subspaces.

Tags: functional-analysis

X is a Banach space, I am given that X is reflexive if every separable subset of X is reflexive.

This, however is not clear to me,
can someoene explain why this is true?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be a continuous linear functional defined on $X.$ Moreover let $$m=\sup_{\{x\in X : ||x||=1\}} f(x) . $$
Then there exists a sequence $v_n \in \{x\in X: ||x||=1\}$ such that $f(v_n )\to m$ as $n\to \infty.$
Let $V$ be the smallest closed linear subspace of $X$ such that $v_n\in V$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N }.$ Of course $V$ is separable linear subspace of $X$ and hence reflexive. Since $g=f|_V$ is continous linear functional defined on $V$ therefore by Theorem of James there exists $v_0\in V, ||v||=1$ such that $$f(v) =m $$ but obviously $v\in\{x\in X: ||x||=1\}$ and again by James theorem we obtain that $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: why is V separable, though? Im really blocked i think

Comment: Because, the set consists of finite rational linear combinations od $v_n$ od dense